# node-refills doesn't load (using webpack)

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, bourbon

Giving `node-refills` a try in an application build with webpack, but imports don't appear to work.

in `webpack.config.js`

```
var NodeRefills = require("node-refills");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass'
      }
    ]
  },

  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: NodeRefills.includePaths
  },
}
```

Doing the same thing with `node-neat`, I can import those assets like this:

in `layout.scss`

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "neat";
```

But in the above instance,

```
@import "refills";
```

Causes webpack build to fail with:

`File to import not found or unreadable: refills`

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: hmm, it looks like node-refills is just a bunch of sass files.  in order to get them into your sass loader and css bundle, you probs have to require node-refills in your js somewhere, not in the webpack config.  Have you tried that?  Perhaps require it in app.js or whatever?

Comment: Yeah, I think `node-neat` is the same way, but that imports fine. Thx.

Comment: Hey @Jamie! I was just looking at this yesterday and I think there is no `@import` for this case. I think bourbon refills is just a set of patterns to copy and paste in their entirety (along with the includePath change). Compared to the neat examples all of the refills and empties examples have a lot going on. There is substantial HTML, CSS and Javascript for each one.

Comment: Hey @noisecapella! That makes sense. I'll be looking for opportunities to apply what I learned about react and redux. We'll see... Thanks for your reply, and hope you're well!